# numpy broadcast addition along arbitrary axes

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to add two arrays with different dimensions by simply performing an identical addition along one or more axes.

A non-vectorized solution:

```
x = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]],[[7,8],[9,0],[1,2]],[[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]],[[9,0],[1,2],[3,4]]]) #shape (4,3,2)
y = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]) #shape (4,2)

ans = np.copy(x)
for i in range(x.shape[1]):
    ans[:,i] += y

print(ans) #shape (4,3,2)
```

How can I broadcast this along the (for example) second axis?  More generally, how can I make this broadcast along arbitrary axes?

Comment: To use `y` with `x` you have to reshape it to (4,1,2). Broadcasting rules are well documented.

Comment: Can you use repmat or tile?

Comment: Is there only one dimension you want to broadcast along? or one of the arrays can be more than 1 dimensions bigger than the other one?

Comment: This apparently is a sequel to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53216750/numpy-add-along-first-axis.  There `y` was (3,2), so broadcasting requires (1,3,2) shape, which is automatic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the shapes of the two arrays:

```
>>> x.shape
(4, 3, 2)
>>> y.shape
(4, 2)
```

You see the addition will need to be broadcasted along the 0th and last axis here. A simple option would be

```
>>> x + y[:, None, :] 
array([[[ 2,  4],
        [ 4,  6],
        [ 6,  8]],

       [[10, 12],
        [12,  4],
        [ 4,  6]],

       [[ 8, 10],
        [10, 12],
        [12, 14]],

       [[16,  8],
        [ 8, 10],
        [10, 12]]])
```

Where,

```
>>> y[:, None, :].shape
(4, 1, 2)
```

Which effectively just changes the strides of `y` so the addition can be broadcasted.

---

Better still, use `np.expand_dims` as suggested by hpaulj in the comments, this'll add an extra penultimate dimension, so you could just do

```
>>> x + np.expand_dims(y, 1)
array([[[ 2,  4],
        [ 4,  6],
        [ 6,  8]],

       [[10, 12],
        [12,  4],
        [ 4,  6]],

       [[ 8, 10],
        [10, 12],
        [12, 14]],

       [[16,  8],
        [ 8, 10],
        [10, 12]]])
```

Comment: I think this answer is correct, OP can use more than one `None` if needed also. unless he's seeking a generalized function that spots the similar dimensions and then adjust the broadcasting.

Comment: His previous question asks about adding a (3,2) array; so he may indeed be focusing on the 'arbitrary'.  In any case, the normal practice is to add a `None` dimension as needed.  The broadcasting rules are well designed to avoid ambiguous cases.

Comment: @anishtain4: "spotting" similar dimensions is in my opinion a bit "dangerous", since it just can "happen" that two dimensions have the same size, but that does not per se means that these are "semantically" the same. This thus could result in a function that frequently works, but every now and then comes up with unintended behavior.